# Spotify in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, spotify

I try to do with simple documentation steps that read on https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/, but also dont work.
    Also try to do with this https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples 
    This is my js file, where I wright request with help documentation.

```
            import axios from 'axios'

                    const state = {todos: []};

                    const getters = {allTodos: (state) => state.todos};

                    const actions = {
                      async fetchTodos({ commit }) {
                      var scopes = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
                      const response = await axios.get('https://cors- 
                      anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize' +
                      '?response_type=code' +'&client_id=' + '0189147f22ed4289a6e8a02db62431d3' +
                      (scopes ? '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes) : '') +
                      '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://192.168.0.102:8080/callback'));
                      commit('setItem', response.data)}};

const mutations = {setItem: (state, todos) => (state.todos = todos)};

export default {state,getters,actions,mutations}
```

But it doesn’t work, what I’m doing wrong, please help??)).

Comment: I need to create App that filter songs, artist...

Comment: What you mean "improved formating"?